# VPN hairpin and port forwarding on ASA 5506x

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

I have a Cisco ASA5506x on which I want

- VPN hairpin so that all VPN traffic goes through the ASA
- A port forwarding for RDP (3389) to my RDP server

I can get them to work separately depending on which rule I have first (I use a network object for the RDP server and a NAT rule for the VPN network (192.168.10.0/24). If i put the "VPN rule" first, then VPN users can access internet, but the port forwarding for RDP doesn't work. If i put the RDP rule first, the port forwarding works but VPN users can't access internet. Am I missing something?

```
: Saved

:
: Serial Number: ...
: Hardware:   ASA5506, 4096 MB RAM, CPU Atom C2000 series 1250 MHz, 1 CPU (4 cores)
:
ASA Version 9.6(1)
!
hostname COMAPNY-ASA5506
enable password abcdef encrypted
names
ip local pool vpn-company-pool 192.168.10.1-192.168.10.50 mask 255.255.255.0

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
nameif outside
security-level 0
ip address dhcp setroute
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
nameif inside
security-level 100
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
shutdown
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
interface Management1/1
management-only
no nameif
no security-level
no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CEST 1
clock summer-time CEDT recurring last Sun Mar 2:00 last Sun Oct 3:00
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network obj_any
subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network server
host 192.168.1.2
object service RDP
service tcp destination eq 3389
description Remote desktop
object network guest-network
subnet 192.168.201.0 255.255.255.0
object network switch-vlan-11
host 192.168.1.253
object network rdp-server
host 192.168.1.2
object network company-internal-network
subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network company-vpn-network
subnet 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_access_in_1 extended permit object RDP any object rdp-server
access-list outside_access_in_1 extended permit ip object company-vpn-network any
access-list vpn-tunnel standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static company-internal-network company-internal-network destination static company-vpn-network company-vpn-network no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (outside,inside) source static company-vpn-network company-vpn-network destination static company-internal-network company-internal-network no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
nat (any,outside) dynamic interface
object network rdp-server
nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 3389 3389
!
nat (outside,outside) after-auto source dynamic company-vpn-network interface
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
access-group outside_access_in_1 in interface outside
route inside 192.168.201.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.253 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
aaa-server ADServer protocol radius
aaa-server ADServer (inside) host 192.168.1.2
key *****
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-DES-SHA ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
enrollment self
subject-name CN=COMPANY-ASA5506
crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
certificate af685359
    308202e8 ... 738993c5
quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
encryption aes-256
integrity sha
group 5 2
prf sha
lifetime seconds 86400
[...]
crypto ikev1 policy 150
authentication pre-share
encryption des
hash sha
group 2
lifetime 86400
telnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
no vpn-addr-assign aaa
no vpn-addr-assign dhcp

dhcp-client client-id interface outside
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
webvpn
cache
disable
error-recovery disable
group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
dns-server value 192.168.1.2
vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec
default-domain value COMPANY.LOCAL
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username jonas password A35MFXE3yjisaBrJ encrypted privilege 15
username jonas attributes
vpn-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
address-pool vpn-company-pool
authentication-server-group Company
default-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
dhcp-server 192.168.1.2
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
peer-id-validate cert
isakmp keepalive disable
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
no authentication chap
authentication ms-chap-v2
!
class-map inspection_default
match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
parameters
message-length maximum client auto
message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
class inspection_default
inspect dns preset_dns_map
inspect ftp
inspect h323 h225
inspect h323 ras
inspect rsh
inspect rtsp
inspect esmtp
inspect sqlnet
inspect skinny
inspect sunrpc
inspect xdmcp
inspect sip
inspect netbios
inspect tftp
inspect ip-options
inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:3...a
: end
```

[image: ASDM configuration]

Comment: Please post your full ASA configuration.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have added the configuration.

Comment: I know this is late to the party and off topic, but I read the question and just about had an accident all over my keyboard. Please DO NOT port forward 3389 under any circumstances. That's a guaranteed way to get hacked. Use an RDS gateway; if you have an RDS server, you have the licensing for a gateway and it's a bazillion times more secure. IF you feel you absolutely must forward 3389, you mustn't, but if you're going to do it anyway, create an ACL to lock it down so only authorized remote IP addresses can connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, changing the obj_any NAT rule to only apply to the inside interface worked for me:

```
object network obj_any
nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
```